# Bash: check if input is empty in pipe

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a bash command `mycommand`. Sometimes it writes something to output but always return exit code 0. I need use pipe to fix the exit code to be 0 for empty output and something else for non-empty output.

```
mycommand | ???
```

I'm not interested in ifs nor custom commands. I want just a simple command like grep with some parameters to check if its input is empty and return the exit code.

Preferably it should print the input if it is not empty but it's not mandatory.

Comment: Why do you "need to use pipe"?

Comment: Not "need", just "want". Anyway this is the best answer I got from comments: `! (mycommand | grep ^)`

Answer (score 7):

#### Maybe:

```
yourcommand | grep -qv .
```

```
! ( yourcommand |  grep -q ^ )
```

Or inverse meaning: return *false* if nothing returned:

```
yourcommand |  grep -q ^ || echo no output.
```

Comment: I know about that but I'd like to avoid the negation. It doesn't matter if its grep or something else.

Comment: Without negation, you have to inverse the meaning of condition.

Comment: If the empty line counts as output (such from the simple `echo`) should test the `^` instead of the `.`. e.g. `echo | grep -q ^ || echo no` vs `echo | grep -q . || echo no`

Comment: I'll go with `! (mycommand | grep ^)` for now (no -q because I want to see the output). Something without the ! would be prefered though.

Comment: Then `grep -v ^` though again, that will not display anything. Your obsession with avoiding the `!` seems irrational.

Comment: @tripleee Already tried that. Doesn't seem to work with my command for some reason (exit code is 1 on empty result). Not sure why. The ! works fine.

Comment: It's not obsession. As I said I'll use it unless there is something better.

Comment: Damn. Turns out I can't use the !. It doesn't work in .travis.yml.

Comment: Try `bash -c '! yourcommand | grep ^'` maybe?

Comment: This doesn't work for an empty line: `printf '\n' | grep -q .` returns 1.

Comment: @l0b0 As remarked above by jm666, the fix is to use `grep ^`

Comment: Solved it. ! works in the end, I just didn't realize it was a special character in YAML. When I put the entire line in quotes it works. Thank you all!

Comment: @tripleee `grep -q ''` same work too, But I can't explain why.

Answer (score 6):

`wc` supports newlines and `\0`:

```
$ printf '\n' | wc -c
1
$ printf '\0' | wc -c
1
```

So this would be a simple POSIX compliant way to do it:

```
mycommand | [ $(wc -c) -eq 0 ]
```

Examples:

```
$ printf '' | [ $(wc -c) -eq 0 ]; echo $?
0
$ printf 'yay' | [ $(wc -c) -eq 0 ]; echo $?
1
$ printf '\n' | [ $(wc -c) -eq 0 ]; echo $?
1
$ printf '\0' | [ $(wc -c) -eq 0 ]; echo $?
1
```

Alternatives which *don't* work:

- `grep .` doesn't match a solitary newline or `\0` as a character:

  ```
  $ printf '\n' | grep .; echo $?
  1
  $ printf '\0' | grep .; echo $?
  1
  ```
- You can't save `\0` in a variable:

  ```
  $ a=$'foo\0bar\0baz'
  $ printf '%s' "$a" | wc -c
  3
  ```
- [Command substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) remove trailing newlines:

  ```
  $ test -z "$(printf '\n')"; echo $?
  0
  ```

Comment: `echo` will return an empty line! Try with `echo -n` or `true`!

Comment: @F.Hauri Fixed. The current solution works for newlines and `\0` as well.

Comment: @l0b0 using the `^` the `grep` will work ...

Answer (score 1):

Because many different answers - so `grep` using the `^`.

```
pp() { printf "================\nfor: %s\n" "$@"; }

pp "no input"
printf '' | grep -q ^ ; echo $?
printf '' | grep -q ^ && echo got input || echo no input

pp 'null character'
printf '\0' | grep -q ^ ; echo $?
printf '\0' | grep -q ^ && echo got input || echo no input

pp '\n'
printf '\n' | grep -q ^ ; echo $?
printf '\n' | grep -q ^ && echo got input || echo no input

pp 'some'
printf 'some' | grep -q ^ ; echo $?
printf 'some' | grep -q ^ && echo got input || echo no input

pp 'some\n'
printf 'some\n' | grep -q ^ ; echo $?
printf 'some' | grep -q ^ && echo got input || echo no input
```

output

```
================
for: no input
1
no input
================
for: null character
0
got input
================
for: \n
0
got input
================
for: some
0
got input
================
for: some\n
0
got input
```

Comment: `pp() { local sline;eval "printf -v sline '%.0s-' {1..$COLUMNS}";printf "%s\nFor: <%s>:\n" $sline "$1";printf "$1" | grep ^ ; echo "Returned code: $?"; }`

Comment: You could run `pp`  without argument, for sample. Then `printf... ${1:-no output}`... But you already know that.

Comment: `read -v COLUMNS < <(tput cols)`, then with fixed input `eval` is not *evil*! There is no issue using `eval` in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the cleanest way is

```sh
mycommand | ( ! grep ^ )
```

Comment: The negation can also be in the very beginning: `! mycommand | grep ^`

Answer (score 0):

A common, though slightly inelegant, workaround is to use a temporary file.

```
t=$(mktemp -t myscript.XXXXXXXX) || exit
# Use a trap to clean up even if interrupted
trap 'rm -f "$t"' EXIT
trap 'exit' HUP TERM
cat >"$t"
if [ -s "$t" ]; then
    : do stuff with "$t"
fi
```

This is obviously too complex to use casually on the command line, but sometimes you just have to write a script.

This generalizes nicely to any situation where you need to perform multiple commands on all of the input.

I will note in passing also `xargs -r` which of course only makes sense if you're piping to `xargs` already.

Comment: Thanks but no thanks. I want an elegant one-liner into my .travis.yml